# Performance impact of method chaining vs creating distinct variables

Tags: javascript

Given a set of operations that filter an array and reduce/sum the results:

```
function arbitrary() {
  return [1,2,3].
    filter((i)=>{return i > 1}).
    reduce((prev,cur)=>{return prev+cur})
}
```

...my assumption is a temporary array is created with the results of filter, and a pointer/reference is passed to reduce.

If this is re-written to use a temporary variable:

```
function arbitrary() {
  var filtered = [1,2,3].filter((i)=>{return i > 1});
  return filtered.reduce((prev,cur)=>{return prev+cur});
}
```

...is it equivalent in terms of memory usage and performance, assuming the variable is garbage collected when it falls out of scope?

*To clarify, I understand that this can be viewed as micro-optimization, and I'm not asking if this is a best-practice.  I'm interested a better understanding of how javascript engines operate internally.*

Comment: Probably it is equivalent, but, if not, at least it's absolutely irrelevant, for sure.

Comment: Stop bothering about microperformance, it's useless 9/10

Comment: `((i)=>{return i > 1})` can be `(i => i > 1)`. There, saved a few chars on transmission, probably a bigger performance hit…

Comment: Basically no difference: http://jsperf.com/js-intermediate-variables/2

Answer (score 2):

This level of micro-optimization is rarely worth modifying your code for.  Write the code the clearest way possible.  I tend to think of these coding priorities in this order: **correct, clear, robust, reusable, commented and with appropriate performance** in basically that order.  Since the performance delta of this question is unlikely to be relevant and it's the last priority, then the other priorities that come before it should guide the thinking.

If you just want to know what's going on internally, you will find there is likely very little difference.

when you run `.filter()` a new array is produced in either one of your code examples.  That part of the operation is not different in either one.

So, the only difference between the two is that in your second code example, you assign that to a temporary variable and then call `.reduce()` on that temporary variable.  No new arrays are produced in the second code example, there is just one additional local variable created and one additional variable assignment.  In the general scheme of what else is doing on in the function (particularly if the array is of any reasonable size), you are making many other function calls so this one extra variable assignment is unlikely to be relevant.

That said, if the intermediate value is not needed for anything else, then many will reason that the code is cleaner by just chaining the results since there's no need for keeping the intermediate result or assigning it or even having that variable.

All that said, this is not a universal truth.  Chaining is not always the better solution.  Sometimes, the code gets so complex that breaking a long giant chained statement up into some named intermediate results makes the code easier to understand and, in some cases, a lot easier to debug (since it's easier to see the intermediate results).  In your particular code, a few chained operations seems perfectly fine so I personally wouldn't use the intermediate variable.

Comment: @juwiley - Did this answer solve your issue? If so, please mark an accepted answer by checking the green checkmark to the left of that answer to indicate to the community that your question has been answered and then both you and the person who provided the answer will earn some reputation points that can lead to more privileges here on StackOverflow.   If this didn't solve your issue, please respond about what else you are confused about.